# Windows 11 surround sound subwoofer output not working

Tags: windows, audio

I have a desktop pc running windows 11 and a 5.1 surround sound amplifier and speakers. I have configured the onboard soundcard of my motherboard (using the windows utility Sound -> More Settings -> Selected the Audio Device -> Configure) for 5.1 surround sound and the amplifier is connected to the correct outputs. 
All the speakers including the subwoofer are working when using the test-button, but when playing music (I tried VLC, Windows media player and the default music player of win 11) or watching videos or streams (I tried multiple programms for each), the subwoofer is not working.
I checked with an oscilloscope on the output of the computers audio jack and there is absolutely no output on the subwoofers connection.
To clarify: The output is there, when I use the test button, but not in any other situation.

All the drivers are up to date. All the other 5 speakers work correctly, so I don't think its a problem of the player-software. As I measured the signal at the output of the pc, it also cant be a issue with the amplifier (that just doesnt receive any input signal).

Edit to answer a comment:
I tried basically every source of sound that I could think of (including true 5.1 sources) and it always yields the same results described above.
As I said, I dont think that its a problem with the source, because why would eg. VLC playing a stereo mp3 file result in output on front left and right, rear left and right and center speakers, but not the subwoofer? If the problem was the fact that the theoretical mp3-file is only stereo, than there should not be any output on the rear and center speakers either, but there is. I also measured these outputs directly (before the amp), so it cant be something in the amplifier detecting stereo audio and generating the rest. 
(My amp would indeed play the same audio going to the front speakers out of the rear and center speakers, if it detected a stereo only source, but that would also reroute the bass to the subwoofer)

I can only think of 1 cause for the problem: It is a windows problem - as in, windows just does not send any audio to the subwoofer-channel of the audio chip.

It cant be a problem with the chip or a connection somewhere, since the test buttons can produce sound from the subwoofer.

FYI: If I connect my phone with a stereo cable to the amp, the rerouting in the amp works and the bass goes to the subwoofer.

Can anyone help me with this/tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using something specifically that will re-assign stereo to 5.1 or are you just assuming it should? Have you tried true 5.1 sources?

Comment: Windows shouldn't be routing stereo to 5.1 unless there is a setting making it do that. I can't test any of this as I no longer have any Win machines here… but back in the days I used Win as HTPC, I needed to get the full Realtek stand-alone drivers to properly enable the outputs. Try https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software [btw, the captcha is pretty annoying. It wants the *answer* to eg 3 + 8 but seems to still reject it. Took me about 8 tries.]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tetsujin! I have now installed this other driver and it fixed at least part of the problem. Now true 5.1 sources work correctly (as in, they produce output on all channels including the sub), but non 5.1 sources still don't work correctly. Stereo sources now create only stereo output on the front left and right speakers...

I also had problems with the captcha, as it didn't believe that 2+3=5... And the download was super slow (max 40kbit/s and that is not my internet connection, i checked) on the 250MB file. (Took me about 3 hours to download it...)

Comment: You now have correct behaviour [apart from the stoopid captcha;)) Stereo is 2.0 not 2.1. It should not invoke the sub.

Comment: In theory yes, that is what stereo is and that is how it would work on a stereo system, but as far as I know, in the case of a stereo source and a surround sound system, windows should automatically 'route' the base to the sub and either everything or a slightly reduced level of the front channels to the rear ones. That would also make a lot of sense, since the amp does exactly that with a stereo source. Its just that my amp cannot detect whether it is getting stereo or surround... I does 'reroute' the audio to the other channels if you select a stereo-only input.

Comment: *"windows should automatically 'route'"* …well, no, it shouldn't. I have a setting on my HTPC amp that will force it to, but by default it shouldn't. I'm an audio engineer by trade, so I hate it when things mess with my sound & do things that they shouldn't be doing; that setting is reserved for parties, just to spread the sound round the room better, as no-one's really listening anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone on the web encounters this problem, I want to share the fix that worked for me:

Fix for Chrome: Added the following command on the google chrome shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-audio-output-resampler --try-supported-channel-layouts --disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess
```

These are other options that I have seen worked for other people but none of this worked for me if only used individually so I ended up trying to combine the 3 options above.

- `--try-supported-channel-layouts`
- `--force-wave-audio`
- `--disable-audio-output-resampler`
- `--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess`
- `--disable-audio-output-resampler`

I also ensured that my output speakers is configured to be using the right settings as 5.1 surround by going to *mmsys.cpl -> select your speakers -> configure speakers -> 5.1 or 7.1 surround*. Click next and so on.

I hope this helps someone.

Edit: I found out from other users about VoiceMeeter and solved the problem on Surround sound.

Comment: So did this solution affect MORE than things playing from just chrome?  This would be interesting to know.

Comment: It actually affects a wide range of applications including media player other browsers and including VLC. Editing the response to update that VoiceMeeter is actually solving the problem I have plus the delays on having multiple different brands of speakers.